# Logs en nginx, en blanco se crean pero no se actualizan

Tags: nginx

Me estoy volviendo loco, me ha dejado de funcionar los logs, los he creado de nuevo, tengo los subdominios con los logs activados, he revisado la configuración de arriba abajo de nginx y no funciona, solo funciona un log que se a creado que pone error.log en /var/log/nginx y ese si se va actualizando cuando inicias nginx, el resto de logs se crean segun como los tengo configurados en site-avalibles, pero están en blanco

Un ejemplo de los logs creados:

> -rw-r----- 1 www-data adm       0 May 26 10:42 blog_access.log
>
> -rw-r----- 1 www-data adm       0 May 26 10:42 blog_error.log

Este es el único que funciona:

> -rw-r----- 1 www-data adm   14591 May 26 12:40 error.log

No entiendo, porque he revisado como he dicho nginx.conf y he buscado por todo el equipo y no encuentro donde nginx le dice que cree ese log y tampoco entiendo, teniendo el resto de logs los mismos permisos y dueños, porque no funcionan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo encontré:

> --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log
>
> --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log

Se compila cuando se instala nginx, pero esto no responde a porque me han dejado de funcionar el resto de logs

Comment: Los log antiguos los había movido a otra ubicación y ahora me doy cuenta que se están actualizando en esa nueva ubicación (/home/backuplogs) aunque en nginx tengo configurada var/log/nginx, si que crea los archivos, pero solo actualiza los antiguos ¿como puede estar pasando esto? site_avalibles/subdomain.conf tengo puesto:         `access_log  /var/log/nginx/blog_access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/blog_error.log;'

Comment: Cualquier archivo abierto por algún proceso en UNIX mantiene la relación con la aplicación siempre que lo muevas dentro del mismo sistema de archivos con un `mv` porque los inodos y descriptores se mantienen invariables. Incluso si borras el archivo éste seguirá ocupando espacio en el sistema de archivos hasta que deje de usarse. Cuando reinicias el servidor `nginx` se cierran los archivos que has movido (dejarán de actualizarse) y se crean los nuevos en el nuevo destino que has configurado.

Comment: Hice de todo los borre, reinicie nginx varias veces, incluso reinicie crontab, al final reiniciando físicamente el servidor empezó a funcionar y me doy cuenta que me pasa con otros procesos, no basta con reiniciar el demonio especifico, una de dos, se abren varios procesos del mismo proceso o systemd no hace bien su trabajo al reiniciar ciertos procesos.

Comment: Si es tu servidor es un `appliance` es probable que los binarios y el proceso de inicio no sea el de la distribución de linux. Suele pasar con algunos VPS "preparados" o "preconfigurados" por algunos proveedores. Debes consultar su soporte para averiguar cómo reiniciar sus servicios (generalmente suelen instalarlos en `/opt` en vez de `/usr` para diferenciarlos).